# Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'Binding<Double>'

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding

I want the user to pick his height through the picker. And then want to record the user's height in inches or centimeters into the Double variable which in my ContenvtView struct. However,  can't assign any value to my @Binding Double. Xcode yelling the thing on the title or says that I can't assign Double to Binding. What am I missing? Here is the code:

struct HeightPicker: View {

```
        @State var foot = 0.0
        @State var inch = 0.0
        @State var meter = 0.0
        @State var cm = 0.0
        @State var measurement = ""
        @Binding var metric: Bool
        @Binding var height: Double
        

        var feet = [Int](0..<10)
        var inches = [Int](0..<12)
        var meters = [Int](0..<3)
        var cms = [Int](0..<100)
        var measurements = ["in", "cm" ]
        
        var body: some View{
            VStack{
                GeometryReader() { geometry in
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        if(metric == false) {
                            
                            Picker(selection: self.$foot, label: Text("")) {
                                ForEach(0 ..< self.feet.count){ index in
                                    Text("\(self.feet[index])").tag(self.feet[index])
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width/4,height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
                            .clipped()
                            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))
                            .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .background(Color.white)
                            
                            Text("\"")
                            
                            
                            Picker(selection: self.$inch, label: Text("")) {
                                ForEach(0 ..< self.inches.count){ index in
                                    Text("\(self.inches[index])").tag(self.inches[index])
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width/4,height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
                            .clipped()
                            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))
                            .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .background(Color.white)

                            var heightInches = (self.foot * 12) + self.inch
                            
                     
                            
                            
                        
                            Text("'")
                        
                            self.$height = heightInches
                            
                        } else if(metric == true) {
                            Picker(selection: self.$meter, label: Text("")) {
                                ForEach(0 ..< self.meters.count){ index in
                                    Text("\(self.meters[index])").tag(self.meters[index])
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width/4, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
                            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))
                            .clipped()
                            .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .background(Color.white)

                            
                            Text("m")
                            
                            
                            Picker(selection: self.$cm, label: Text("")) {
                                ForEach(0 ..< self.cms.count){ index in
                                    Text("\(self.cms[index])").tag(self.cms[index])
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width/4,height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
                            .clipped()
                            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))
                            .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .background(Color.white)

                            Text("cm")


                        }
                        
                    }
              
                    
                }.frame(height: 45)
            }
            .frame(height: 45)
            .padding(.top,5)
            .padding(.bottom, 5)
            
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What about `self.height = heightInches`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot just do this in the middle of a view:

```
var heightInches = (self.foot * 12) + self.inch
self.$height = heightInches
```

Try this as an example:

```
struct HeightPicker: View {
    
    @State var foot: Int = 0    // <---
    @State var inch: Int = 0    // <---
    @State var meter: Int = 0   // <---
    @State var cm: Int = 0  // <---
    @State var measurement = ""
    
    @Binding var metric: Bool
    @Binding var height: Double
    
    var feet = [Int](0..<10)
    var inches = [Int](0..<12)
    var meters = [Int](0..<3)
    var cms = [Int](0..<100)
    var measurements = ["in", "cm" ]
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            GeometryReader() { geometry in
                
                HStack {
                    
                    if !metric {    // <---
                        
                        Picker(selection: self.$foot, label: Text("")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< self.feet.count){ index in
                                Text("\(self.feet[index])").tag(self.feet[index])
                            }
                        }
                        // add this
                        .onChange(of: foot) { _ in
                            self.height = Double(self.foot * 12 + self.inch)
                            print("--> height: \(height)")
                        }
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/4,height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
                        .clipped()
                        .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))
                        .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .background(Color.white)
                        
                        Text("\"")
                        
                        Picker(selection: self.$inch, label: Text("")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< self.inches.count){ index in
                                Text("\(self.inches[index])").tag(self.inches[index])
                            }
                        }
                        // add this
                        .onChange(of: inch) { _ in
                            self.height = Double(self.foot * 12 + self.inch)
                            print("--> height: \(height)")
                        }
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/4,height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
                        .clipped()
                        .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))
                        .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .background(Color.white)
 
                        Text("'")

                    } else {
                        Picker(selection: self.$meter, label: Text("")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< self.meters.count){ index in
                                Text("\(self.meters[index])").tag(self.meters[index])
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/4, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
                        .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))
                        .clipped()
                        .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .background(Color.white)
                        
                        Text("m")
                        
                        Picker(selection: self.$cm, label: Text("")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< self.cms.count){ index in
                                Text("\(self.cms[index])").tag(self.cms[index])
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/4,height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
                        .clipped()
                        .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))
                        .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .background(Color.white)
                        
                        Text("cm")
                    }
                }
            }.frame(height: 45)
        }
        .frame(height: 45)
        .padding(.top,5)
        .padding(.bottom, 5)
    }
}
```

Comment: if this answer your question, please click the checkmark next to the post.